# android adb - how to set emulator to ac power

Tags: android, adb

In an effort to test doze and standby mode im trying to change the battery level and also the set to ac etc using adb and a api 23 emulator.

But when i run the following bash command:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery set level [95]
```

i get the following error:

```
Bad value: [95]
```

also when i run :

```
adb shell dumpsys battery set [ac]
```

i get the following error:

```
Dump current battery state, or:
  set [ac|usb|wireless|status|level|invalid] <value>
  unplug
  reset
```

i am assuming meaning it could not find the ac command.  How can i change the emulator to ac and also update the battery level ?

update: there is a command `adb shell dumpsys battery unplug`
 to unplug the emulator so should there not be a command to plug it in for AC power ?

Comment: You shoud exclude the square brackets

Comment: Also documentation describes slightly different steps for testing it: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#testing_doze_and_app_standby

Comment: i would like a  way to emulator the device being PLUGED in.   i tried without the square brackets, same results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> there is a command adb shell dumpsys battery unplug to unplug the
>   emulator so should there not be a command to plug it in for AC power ?

Yes, the command is:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery set ac 1
```

To change the level of the battery you can use this command:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery set level 42
```

Comment: and adb shell dumpsys battery set ac 0 turns off the ac. exactly what i needed, thank you. Doze mode should be completely disabled when in ac 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to test Doze, I recommend trying the commands directly from the Developer Site [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).

The commands to cycle through Doze modes are as follows:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle -h
```

And for testing App Standby:

To force your app into App Standby mode:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
$ adb shell am set-inactive <packageName> true
```

To simulate waking your app:

```
$ adb shell am set-inactive <packageName> false
$ adb shell am get-inactive <packageName>
```